# Sorting IP Addresses in Ruby 1.8

Tags: ruby, ip-address

I am trying to sort some ip addresses in ascending order using ipaddr. Not sure why this is not working. After I run my custom sort, the order is not affected.

```
require 'ipaddr'
ip_array = Array.new
ip_array2 = Array.new

ip_array = ["d1.mysite.com",
            "d3.mysite.com",
            "d2.mysite.com",
            "d6.mysite.com",
            "d32.mysite.com",
            "d5.mysite.com",
            "d9.mysite.com",
            "d34.mysite.com"]



 ## First, get IP addresses and push onto ip_array2
 ip_array.each { |x| ip_array2.push(IPSocket::getaddress(x))  }

 ## Let's see the unsorted array contents
 ip_array2.each { |x| puts x }


 ## Now, sort IP addresses in ip_array2
 ip_array2.sort { |a,b| IPAddr.new( a ) <=> IPAddr.new( b ) } 

 ## Let's see the sorted array contents
 ip_array2.each { |x| puts x }
```

---

```
BEFORE SORT (1st 3 octets are identical)
```

---

```
xxx.xx.xx.78
xxx.xx.xx.114
xxx.xx.xx.54
xxx.xx.xx.57
xxx.xx.xx.58
xxx.xx.xx.79
xxx.xx.xx.81
xxx.xx.xx.100
```

---

```
AFTER SORT (1st 3 octets are identical)
```

---

```
xxx.xx.xx.78
xxx.xx.xx.114
xxx.xx.xx.54
xxx.xx.xx.57
xxx.xx.xx.58
xxx.xx.xx.79
xxx.xx.xx.81
xxx.xx.xx.100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort` is not in place. Either call `sort!` or assign the result from sort to `ip_array2`.

Comment: Thanks. No change in sort order...Weird

Comment: sort_by is not in place. Call `sort_by!` to change ip_array2 or assign the result of sort_by to ip_array2. Same holds true for the call you are making by the way. Use `sort!` to do the sorting in place

Comment: Sorry for the long and redundant answer, now I see your solution is correct and you only needed the in place bit from my comment. Changing my answer.

Comment: I do appreciate it and yes, that change fixed the issue